# Download 40M zip file using PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have a 40M zip file that is at a web address of say http://info/data/bigfile.zip that I would like to download to my local server. What is the best way currently to download a zip file of that size using PHP or header requests such that it won't time out at 8M or give me a 500 error? Right now, I keep getting timed out.

Comment: curl...........

Comment: You can increase time out time in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to download large file via php try something like this (source http://teddy.fr/2007/11/28/how-serve-big-files-through-php/):

```
<?php
define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*1024); // Size (in bytes) of tiles chunk

// Read a file and display its content chunk by chunk
function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) {
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt    = 0;
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');

    if ($handle === false) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
        echo $buffer;
        ob_flush();
        flush();

        if ($retbytes) {
            $cnt += strlen($buffer);
        }
    }

    $status = fclose($handle);

    if ($retbytes && $status) {
        return $cnt; // return num. bytes delivered like readfile() does.
    }

    return $status;
}

// Here goes your code for checking that the user is logged in
// ...
// ...

    $filename = 'path/to/your/file';  // url of your file
    $mimetype = 'mime/type';
    header('Content-Type: '.$mimetype );
    readfile_chunked($filename);

?>
```

**Second solution **

Copy the file one small chunk at a time

```
/**
 * Copy remote file over HTTP one small chunk at a time.
 *
 * @param $infile The full URL to the remote file
 * @param $outfile The path where to save the file
 */
function copyfile_chunked($infile, $outfile) {
    $chunksize = 10 * (1024 * 1024); // 10 Megs

    /**
     * parse_url breaks a part a URL into it's parts, i.e. host, path,
     * query string, etc.
     */
    $parts = parse_url($infile);
    $i_handle = fsockopen($parts['host'], 80, $errstr, $errcode, 5);
    $o_handle = fopen($outfile, 'wb');

    if ($i_handle == false || $o_handle == false) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
        $parts['path'] .= '?' . $parts['query'];
    }

    /**
     * Send the request to the server for the file
     */
    $request = "GET {$parts['path']} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request .= "Host: {$parts['host']}\r\n";
    $request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n";
    $request .= "Keep-Alive: 115\r\n";
    $request .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($i_handle, $request);

    /**
     * Now read the headers from the remote server. We'll need
     * to get the content length.
     */
    $headers = array();
    while(!feof($i_handle)) {
        $line = fgets($i_handle);
        if ($line == "\r\n") break;
        $headers[] = $line;
    }

    /**
     * Look for the Content-Length header, and get the size
     * of the remote file.
     */
    $length = 0;
    foreach($headers as $header) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Content-Length:') === 0) {
            $length = (int)str_replace('Content-Length: ', '', $header);
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start reading in the remote file, and writing it to the
     * local file one chunk at a time.
     */
    $cnt = 0;
    while(!feof($i_handle)) {
        $buf = '';
        $buf = fread($i_handle, $chunksize);
        $bytes = fwrite($o_handle, $buf);
        if ($bytes == false) {
            return false;
        }
        $cnt += $bytes;

        /**
         * We're done reading when we've reached the conent length
         */
        if ($cnt >= $length) break;
    }

    fclose($i_handle);
    fclose($o_handle);
    return $cnt;
}
```

Adjust the $chunksize variable to your needs. This has only been mildly tested. It could easily break for a number of reasons.

Usage:

```
copyfile_chunked('http://somesite.com/somefile.jpg', '/local/path/somefile.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of detail given, but it sounds like php.ini defaults are restricting the servers ability to transfer large files via php web interface in a timely manner.

Namely these settings `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize`, or `max_execution_time`

Might jump in your php.ini file, up the sizes, restart Apache, and retry the file transfer.

HTH